# Parsing Gmail Email content in HTML Format (Table) into Google SpreadSheet Columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having two issues Parsing Data from Gmail Email HTML Table into Googlesheet Columns

#### Issue 1:

Getting Data from the Body

1. If the Email Body comes formatted as a HTML Table the method getPlainBody() only takes the Paragrapgh before the Table, but nothing else, so there is nothing to parse.

1.1 When I remove the HTML Table format it works, bring the Data into the Body Column.

So how can I retrieve the Content of the HTML Table into a body Field?

PLAIN EMAIL - NOT HTML FORMATTING

```
Rental Unit 404 Rupert Street

Renter Full Name Test

Email Address testing@testing.com

Phone 7779999999

Check In Date  Wed Jun 19 2019

Check Out Date  Sun Jul 19 2020

Additional Comments Testing

How did you hear about Us?  Testing
```

#### Issue 2

Parsing Data into separate Columns when I used not formatted text

2. toString() seems to be deprecated and therefore, code complains about it

2.1. If i remove the toString() then columns are separated by it displays the Object Reference, instead of the actual Data

I tried to replace toString by getText but it did not work.

So how what method should I use to bring the text instead of the Object Reference?

```js
    //Displays Menu Option in GoogleSheet
    function onOpen(e) {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      
      ui.createMenu("Parse Customer Requests")
      .addItem("Get Emails","getGmailEmails")
      .addToUi();
    }
    
    //Gets Emails with Rental Tag
    function getGmailEmails(){    
      var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Rental");
      var threads = label.getThreads();
      
      var i;
      
      for(i = threads.length - 1; i >= 0; i --){
       var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        
        var j;
        for (j=0; j<messages.length; j++){
          var message = messages[j];
          extractDetails(message);
          GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
        }
        
        threads[i].removeLabel(label);      
      }   
    }
    
    //Extract Details from Email
    function extractDetails(message){
     //var datetime       = message.getDate();
     //var subjectText    = message.getSubject();
     //var senderDetails  = message.getFrom();
     //var bodyContents   = message.getPlainBody();
     
      var emailData = {
        body:                 "Null",
        date:                 "Null",
        subject:              "Null",
        rentalUnit:           "Null",
        renterFullName:       "Null",
        emailAddress:         "Null",
        phone:                "Null",
        checkInDate:          "Null",
        checkOut:             "Null",
        additionalComments:   "Null",
        howDidYouHearAboutUs: "Null"
      }  
      
      var emailKeywords = {
        rentalUnit:           "Rental Unit",
        renterFullName:       "Renter Full Name",
        emailAddress:         "Email Address",
        phone:                "Phone",
        checkInDate:          "Check In Date",
        checkOutDate:         "Check Out Date",
        additionalComments:   "Additional Comments",
        howDidYouHearAboutUs: "How Did you hear about Us?"
        
      }  
      
      emailData.date    = message.getDate();
      emailData.subject = message.getSubject();
      emailData.sender  = message.getFrom();
      emailData.body    = message.getPlainBody();
      
      var regExp;
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.rentalUnit + ").*");
      emailData.rentalUnit = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.renterFullName + ").*");
      emailData.renterFullName = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.emailAddress + ").*");
      emailData.emailAddress = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.phone + ").*");
      emailData.phone = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.checkInDate + ").*");
      emailData.checkInDate = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.checkOutDate + ").*");
      emailData.checkOutDate = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.additionalComments + ").*");
      emailData.additionalComments = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp ("(?<=" + emailKeywords.howDidYouHearAboutUs + ").*");
      emailData.howDidYouHearAboutUs = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      
     var activeSheet    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     
     var emailDataArray = [];
     
      for (var columnName in emailData){
        emailDataArray.push(emailData[columnName]);
      }    
     activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArray);     
    }
```

Comment: I was wrong and the issue that I said it was related to a deprecated toString, was incorrect it is working with plain text now. The only remaining issue is how to read from a HTML Table format table

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour (I'm getting the data from a table with `getPlainBody()`, but can't you use [getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody()) instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have figured it out. It required a few more changes and ended using getRawContent() instead.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. Would you consider posting an answer explaining what the issue was?

Comment: I am still cleaning a few things. I will post when done..